# Calculator App Problem - 0 at the Beginning and Dot in Number

Tags: java, android, calculator

I have been working on android-studio calculator. I'm at a very beginner and I have two problems. First when I press "c" in my app it works fine on the first click. Then when I click on it and click any number it shows "0x" (x is that number).

My second problem is how can I add only one dot? I tried with String.contains() but it didn't work. How can I fix this?
Here is my XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="6"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cc"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="C"
            android:textColor="#d75700"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="nrClear"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="undo"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:onClick="goBack"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/division"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="pressDivision"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/multip"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="*"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="pressMultiplication"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nr1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="firstNumber"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nr2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="secondNumber"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nr3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="thirdNumber"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="pressMinus"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nr4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="fourthNumber"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nr5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="fifthNumber"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nr6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="sixthNumber"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="pressPlus"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nr7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="seventhNumber"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nr8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="eightNumber"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nr9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="ninthNumber"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="="
            android:textSize="30dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:textSize="30dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/procent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="%"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="pressProcent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nr0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="pressZero"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="."
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="pressDot"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="="
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:onClick="pressEquals"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And code:

```
String operation;
CharSequence num1;
CharSequence num2;
TextView t;
String n1;
String n2;
String doot;
double number1;
double number2;
double output;
String out;
CharSequence temp;
CharSequence dooot;
int x;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    operation = "";
    num2 = "";
    n1 = "";
    n2 = "";
    doot = "";
    number1 = 1;
    number2 = 0;
    output = 0;
    out = "";
    temp = "";
    x=100;
    dooot=".";
}

public void firstNumber(View view) {
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    temp = t.getText();
    if (temp.equals("0")) {
        t.setText("1");
    } else t.append("1");
}

public void secondNumber(View view) {
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    temp = t.getText();
    if (temp.equals("0")) {

        t.setText("2");
    } else t.append("2");
}

public void thirdNumber(View view) {
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    temp = t.getText();
    if (temp.equals("0")) {
        t.clearComposingText();
        t.setText("3");
    } else t.append("3");
}

public void fourthNumber(View view) {
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    temp = t.getText();
    if (temp.equals("0")) {
        t.clearComposingText();
        t.setText("4");
    } else t.append("4");
}

public void fifthNumber(View view) {
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    temp = t.getText();
    if (temp.equals("0")) {
        t.clearComposingText();
        t.setText("5");
    } else t.append("5");
}

public void sixthNumber(View view) {
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    temp = t.getText();
    if (temp.equals("0")) {
        t.clearComposingText();
    num1 = "";
        t.setText("6");
    } else t.append("6");
}

public void seventhNumber(View view) {
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    temp = t.getText();
    if (temp.equals("0")) {
        t.clearComposingText();
        t.setText("7");
    } else t.append("7");
}

public void eightNumber(View view) {
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    temp = t.getText();
    if (temp.equals("0")) {
        t.clearComposingText();
        t.setText("8");
    } else t.append("8");
}

public void ninthNumber(View view) {
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    temp = t.getText();
    if (temp.equals("0")) {
        t.clearComposingText();
        t.setText("9");
    } else t.append("9");
}

public void pressZero(View view) {
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    temp = t.getText();
    if (!temp.equals("0")) {
        t.append("0");
    }
}

public void goBack(View view){
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    temp = t.getText();
    if(!temp.equals("0")) {
        if(n1.length()==1)
        {
            number1=0;
            t.setText("");
            out = String.valueOf(number1);
            t.append(out);
        }
        else {
            num1 = t.getText();
            n1 = num1.toString();
            n1 = n1.substring(0, n1.length() - 1);
            number1 = Integer.parseInt(n1);
            t.setText("");
            out = String.valueOf(number1);
            t.append(out);
        }
    }
}

public void pressPlus(View view)
{
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    num1=t.getText();
    t.setText("0");
    operation="+";
}

public void pressMinus(View view)
{
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    num1=t.getText();
    t.setText("0");
    operation="-";
}

public void pressMultiplication(View view)
{
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    num1=t.getText();
    t.setText("0");
    operation="*";
}

public void pressDivision(View view)
{
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    num1=t.getText();
    t.setText("0");
    operation="/";
}

public void pressProcent(View view)
{
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    num1=t.getText();
    n1 = num1.toString();
    number1 = Integer.parseInt(n1);
    output = number1 / x;
    t.setText("");
    out= String.valueOf(output);
    out = out.indexOf(".")< 0 ? out : out.replaceAll("0*$", "").replaceAll("\\.$", "");
    t.append(out);
}

public void pressDot(View view)
{
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    doot=t.toString();

    if (doot.contains(dooot))t.append(".");
    else t.append("");

}

public void nrClear(View view)
{
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    t.setText("0");
}

public void pressEquals(View view)
{
    if(operation.equals("+"))
    {
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        num2 = t.getText();
        n1 = num1.toString();
        n2 = num2.toString();
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(n1);
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(n2);
        output = number1 + number2;
    }

    if(operation.equals("-"))
    {
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        num2 = t.getText();
        n1 = num1.toString();
        n2 = num2.toString();
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(n1);
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(n2);
        output = number1 - number2;
    }

    if(operation.equals("*"))
    {
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        num2 = t.getText();
        n1 = num1.toString();
        n2 = num2.toString();
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(n1);
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(n2);
        output = number1 * number2;
    }

    if(operation.equals("/"))
    {
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        num2 = t.getText();
        n1 = num1.toString();
        n2 = num2.toString();
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(n1);
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(n2);
        output = number1 / number2;
    }


    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    t.setText("");
    out= String.valueOf(output);
    out = out.indexOf(".")< 0 ? out : out.replaceAll("0*$", "").replaceAll("\\.$", "");
    t.append(out);
}

}
```

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first problem, do the following:

```
public void eightNumber(View view) {
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    temp = t.getText();
    temp = temp + "8"

    //convert the input number to double to avoid extra zero before digits (05)
    double tempNumber = Double.parseDouble(temp);
    //convert our double number back to string, to use it in textView.setText method
    temp = String.valueOf(tempNumber);

    //to avoid redundant ".0" after integer numbers:
    //if 2 last digits of the number is .0, we delete it
    if(temp.lastIndexOf(".0") == temp.length() - 2){
        temp = temp.substring(0, temp.length() - 2);
    }

    t.setText(temp);
}
```

and so on for all 9 digits.
But your second question, you just need to reverese the if condition:

```
public void pressDot(View view)
{
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    doot=t.toString();

    if (!doot.contains(dooot)) {
        t.append(".");
    }

}
```

And there is no need for else block.
Let me know if you need more help please.

Comment: And you can avoid some redundant code too, for example instead of 9 similar firstNumber, secondNumber ... method, you can have only one method for example addNumber(View view), and use this method for all number buttons' onClick method, and use a simple switch-case block to determine which number is pressed and the digit you should add.
Like this: switch(view.getId()){ case R.id.nr9: ....}

Comment: Thanks for tips, works fine but new problem arose. Program is crashing when i click dot and then a digit. Why?

Comment: You are welcome, first of all you should see the Exception which is occurred in log cat, that helps.
Anyway I can guest your exception, it is **NumberFormatException** , right? Because when you put a dot in your number it's not an integer anymore, it's a float number and this line: **Integer.parseInt(temp);** throws NumberFormatException, you can use double instead of integer, I will change my answer. Take a look at edited answer please and let me know if the issue is resolved.

Comment: Works nice, thank you so much. What can i do if i want to set "/" instead of "0" when i press "/" button? And then if i press number "/" disappears. I can't do t.setText("/") because it crashes. Same with "-" and "*".

Comment: You're welcome. Yes it crashes if you add (*, +, /, -) to your textview because of the same previous problem (number format exception). The simplest solution is what you have already done (clearing the textView after pressing operators (*, +, /, -) and wait for user to enter the next number). **But** if you insist to show users numbers an operators together for a better appearance, that would be more simple and nice to add a new TextView to your xml layout, with a smaller font and show the whole equation line (3234 + 1233221 for instance) in the new textView.

Comment: I have one more problem. I edited void pressZero and when it is 0.00 or something like 0.0 and I click any of digit then it shows 009. I know that, this is because of line "temp = String.valueOf(tempNumber).replace(".0","");", but it can't be deleted. What can I do with this one? Sorry for so many questions.

Comment: By the way mark my answer as "accepted" if it has resolved your question please. And let me know if you have got more questions.

Comment: It's alright, for your last problem I will edit my answer, take a look at it please.

Comment: I changed your code because it required string and it doesn't work(it's adding .0 to every dignity). What should I do? Code:
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        temp = t.getText();
        temp = temp + "9";
        s=temp.toString();
        
        if(s.lastIndexOf(".0") == s.length() - 2){
            s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 2);
        }

        double tempOut= Double.parseDouble(s);
        CharSequence tempOli = String.valueOf(tempOut);

        t.setText(tempOli);
}

Comment: That was a missing "temp." before substring method. I did correct it with additional commands. check it out please and let me know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Found a error:

```
public void pressDot(View view)
{
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    doot=t.getText().toString(); //should be this

    if (doot.contains(dooot))t.append(".");
    else t.append("");

}
```